# Asynchronous long running computation in elm

Tags: asynchronous, task, elm

I am new to ELM and I am trying to wrap my head around asynchronous computations.

I am trying to write an ELM program to automate radiology report generation.
This program uses a graph data structure to store the state of a hierarchical tree of toggles, radio, and edit boxes that the user can edit (add, delete, move around) the toggles.
Individual toggles can also have their behavior modified so that toggling one ON, will show or hide other toggles.
As an example, when you toggled **Chest** ON, the **lung** would show, and the **liver** would be hidden. I do this by using the edges of the graph in the `update` function, which then is interpreted and rendered in the `view` function.
I then use a look-up table of sorts to compute the English phrase corresponding to a set of specific ON or OFF toggles, like **liver**, **cyst**, **3**, **mm**, **segment_4**.
This works fine, but computing the English phrases is computationally expensive and it blocks my UI thread.

I have been playing with `Tasks` and `Process.swap` but I am misunderstanding them somehow.
I thought that I could change my `ToggleOnOff` message implementation so that I could spawn the long running implementation, return immediately my new state (i.e., (model, Cmd msg) ), and set the spawned processed to call the update again with the English text string when it finished with the computation. I have failed completely in implementing this.

I have a `generateReport` function which I turned into a Task using `Task.succeed`.
Than I tried to spawn this `generateReportTask` and chain it using `Task.andThen` to the msg `UpdateReportFullText`. And then I would need to return a new model imediately with the state of the toggles, before the long running `generateReportTask` runs and calls update on its own to add the english text to the model.

I believe I am still thinking about this imperatively and that I am misunderstanding FP and ELM. My experience with ELM has always shown me that the ELM way is always shorter and clearer than my clumsy imperative-style noob attempts.

Can someone please educate me and help a poor fellow see the light?
Thank you
(Sorry for the dry no code question but my program is hard to reproduce in a few lines...)

Comment: I don't think that that type of process spawning really works in Elm. I would suggest you use a webworker in javascript and link it to your elm using ports

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Long running computations are a bit tricky on the web platform, especially if you want them not to block the user interface.

In practice you have two options:

1. **Use [Web Workers](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Web_Workers_API/Using_web_workers)**. This is a technology that actually spins up a new process that can run entirely in parallel with your UI process. Unfortunately Web Workers are basically an entirely separate program that communicates with your main program via (mostly) serialised messages. This means that the computation you perform has to be accelerated more than the serialization/deserialization ends up costing.

   In Elm, you would use a `Platform.worker` program, then add ports and wire things together in JavaScript. [This article seems to describe this in some detail](https://www.lindsaykwardell.com/blog/utilizing-elm-in-a-web-worker/).
2. You can chunk up your computation into small bits and perform each small bit per frame. This can work even better in some cases where there are intermediate results that can be rendered, although this isn't necessary. You can see an [example I wrote here](https://elm-visualization.netlify.app/forcedirectedgraph/) (notice how it actually takes a few seconds to compute the layout of the graph, but it just looks like a neat little animation).